# Rolling Update Of docker containers in GCP Instance Group

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying a Java Spring Boot container inside a VM in a instance group in GCP.
So each VM will have one Spring Boot container.
I am looking to achieve a rolling update of the containers.

- I can use docker compose to remove the latest container, pull the image (from a docker registry) and then recreate the container.
- But the containers are in different VMs under a single instance group in GCP, how do I do a rolling update across VMs?
- I am using unmanaged instance group where each VM is having the docker container of the spring boot application running in it.

Comment: If you are using a Managed Instance Group, then perform a rolling replace of the instances and NOT the containers within the instance. Edit your question to specify the instance group type and how containers are run on each instance (Docker or Container OS). The details determine the procedure to follow.

Comment: Since you are using Docker on an Unmanaged Instance Group, you must manually update each instance, write your own automation software or use a third-party product. It would be simple to write a Python application that connected to each instance and ran a set of shell commands. Another option would be to create a startup script the pulls the latest container on startup. Then you could use the CLI to restart each instance. The issue that you will have is removing an instance from the load balancer, updating, and then putting the instance back.

Comment: I would redesign and use Managed Instance Groups and Compute Optimized OS. then you could use managed rolling replacements.

Comment: @Wojtek_B has provided a good answer based upon the information provided in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many apporoaches to this topic - as [John Hanley pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833043/rolling-update-of-docker-containers-in-gcp-instance-group/68847822#comment121665190_68833043) you can manually update each VM in the Unmanaged Instance Group but the easier way would be to use some scripting to do this. You can even use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works) for that but in case of just a few VM's it's a total overkill.

Easy way (using only what GCP offeres) to perform a [rolling update of your container on all VM's inside the group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups) it's best to use Managed Intance Group. It will actually replace your VM's so if you store some data on their disks it's best to use a [Stateful MIG](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs#stateful_configuration).

Simple way to set up everything is:

1. Create an instance and cofigure it to your needs.
2. Stop the VM & [create a disk image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images) from it's disk.
3. [Create instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) and select custom disk image (that you just created)
4. Create a Stateful Managed Instance Group

At this point you can create a service that will be your back-end and put some load-balancer in front of it if you need to do so. You can set up some [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler) & [autohealing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs) of your MIG in case heavy load or some unresponsive VM's needs restarting.

If you want to update your VM's (or the constainers they run) repeat steps 1-3 with new configuration. Or if it's something simple you can use startup scripts that will run every time a new VM is created for your group.
When you have a new group, go to the VM groups page and select the one you want to update, in the details click "Update VMs" button at the top.

[image]

In the new page under "New Tamplate" select from the dropdown list the new one you created.
[image]

At this point just click "Update VM's" blue button at the bottom and wait for results. In a few minutes your VM's should be updated and showing to use a new instance template.

While updating you will see both templates being used:

[image]

When you know the process it's quite easy, it requires some "clicking" though.

You can always go the "hard way" and set up your own automation.

Lastly - [pulling latest Docker images](http://There%20are%20many%20apporoaches%20to%20this%20topic%20-%20as%20John%20Hanley%20pointed%20out%20you%20can%20manually%20update%20each%20VM%20in%20the%20Unmanaged%20Instance%20Group%20but%20the%20easier%20wold%20be%20to%20use%20some%20scripting%20to%20do%20this.%20You%20can%20even%20use%20Ansible%20for%20that%20but%20in%20case%20of%20just%20a%20few%20VM%27s%20it%27s%20a%20total%20overkill.%20%20Easy%20way%20to%20perform%20a%20%5Brolling%20update%20of%20your%20container%20on%20all%20VM%27s%20inside%20the%20group%5D%5B1%5D%20it%27s%20best%20to%20use%20Managed%20Intance%20Group.%20It%20will%20actually%20replace%20your%20VM%27s%20so%20if%20you%20store%20some%20data%20on%20their%20disks%20it%27s%20best%20to%20use%20a%20%5BStateful%20MIG%5D%5B2%5D.%20%20Simple%20way%20to%20set%20up%20everything%20is:%20%201.%20Create%20an%20instance%20and%20cofigure%20it%20to%20your%20needs.%202.%20Stop%20the%20VM%20&%20%5Bcreate%20a%20disk%20image%5D%5B3%5D%20from%20it%27s%20disk.%203.%20%5BCreate%20instance%20template%5D%5B4%5D%20and%20select%20custom%20disk%20(that%20you%20just%20created)%204.%20Create%20a%20Stateful%20Managed%20Instance%20Group%20%20At%20this%20point%20you%20can%20create%20a%20service%20that%20will%20be%20your%20back-end%20and%20put%20some%20load-balancer%20in%20front%20of%20it%20if%20you%20need%20to%20do%20so.%20You%20can%20set%20up%20some%20%5Bautoscaling%5D%5B5%5D%20&%20%5Bautohealing%5D%5B6%5D%20of%20your%20MIG%20in%20case%20heavy%20load%20or%20some%20unresponsive%20VM%27s%20needs%20restarting.%20%20If%20you%20want%20to%20update%20your%20VM%27s%20(or%20the%20constainers%20they%20run)%20repeat%20steps%201-3%20with%20new%20configuration.%20Or%20if%20it%27s%20something%20simple%20you%20can%20use%20startup%20scripts%20that%20will%20run%20every%20time%20a%20new%20VM%20is%20created%20for%20your%20group.%20When%20you%20have%20a%20new%20group,%20go%20to%20the%20VM%20groups%20page%20and%20select%20the%20one%20you%20want%20to%20update,%20in%20the%20details%20click%20%22Update%20VMs%22%20button%20at%20the%20top.%20%20%5B!%5Benter%20image%20description%20here%5D%5B7%5D%5D%5B7%5D%20%20In%20the%20new%20page%20under%20%22New%20Tamplate%22%20select%20from%20the%20dropdown%20list%20the%20new%20one%20you%20created.%20%5B!%5Benter%20image%20description%20here%5D%5B8%5D%5D%5B8%5D%20%20At%20this%20point%20just%20click%20%22Update%20VM%27s%22%20blue%20button%20at%20the%20bottom%20and%20wait%20for%20results.%20In%20a%20few%20minutes%20your%20VM%27s%20should%20be%20updated%20and%20showing%20to%20use%20a%20new%20instance%20template.%20%20While%20updating%20you%20will%20see%20both%20templates%20being%20used:%20%20%5B!%5Benter%20image%20description%20here%5D%5B9%5D%5D%5B9%5D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups%20%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs#stateful_configuration%20%20%20%5B3%5D:%20https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images%20%20%20%5B4%5D:%20https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates%20%20%20%5B5%5D:%20https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler%20%20%20%5B6%5D:%20https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs%20%20%20%5B7%5D:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1MaQ.png%20%20%20%5B8%5D:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSTj8.png%20%20%20%5B9%5D:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOSJg.png) at the start ([using startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux)) seems also a very good idea since you can just "Restart / Replace" VM's in your group and after the restart all VM's will start serving new container.